CMake and finding header files in a directory tree
Here's my directory structure for my project (abbreviated):
Drawbox/
    Library/
        Drawbox.cpp
    APClass/
        smallAPstring.h

Here's the top level CMakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(my-project)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} . Library APClass Library/jpeg)

add_library(Drawbox STATIC)

add_subdirectory(Library)
add_subdirectory(Tools)
add_subdirectory(APClass)

target_compile_features(Drawbox PUBLIC cxx_std_11)

And here's the one for the Library directory:
target_sources(Drawbox
    PRIVATE
        Color.cpp  DrErrMessages.cpp DrEventQ.cpp 
        DrawboxWindow.cpp FinePoint.cpp Image.cpp 
        JpegReader.cpp 
        PVector.cpp Point.cpp Rect.cpp SpaceCalc.cpp Timer.cpp
        SDL/Drawbox.SDL.cpp  SDL/Keyboard.SDL.cpp
)

But I'm finding that a Drawbox.cpp located in the Library sub-directory doesn't find smallAPstring.h when doing
#include “smallAPstring.h"

What I really want to say is, “All source files in all subdirectories should find include files in these directories.”  Can that be said? Or should I be putting something in my sub-directory CMakeLists.txt files?

Yes, but I don't think that's relevant. These subdirectories don't contain targets, only lists of files. There is only one target in the entire setup.  Or am I missing something?

I expected each of the add_subdirectory(APClass)  were separate library targets. In any case it's not clear why include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} . Library APClass Library/jpeg) didn't work.

Maybe you can refer the Cmake doc
Have you add target_include_directories owing to you have a complex project?
I think it's better.
